# An error with QMenuBar in PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I've tried to put a MenuBar but it doesn't appear, and I don't know what I doing wrong.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys


class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):

  def __init__(self):
    super(Window, self).__init__()
    self.setWindowTitle("IDE")
    self.initUI

  def initUI(self):

    grid = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)
    menuBar = QtGui.QMenuBar(self)
    self.fileMenu = menuBar.addMenu("File")

    grid.addWidget(menuBar, 0, 0)

    self.setLayout(grid)
```

and the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to set the menubar on the main window

```
self.setMenuBar(menuBar)
```

In many cases, you don't need to create the menubar manually, you can just call `.menuBar()` on the main window and it will return the current one or create one if it doesn't exist.  This is the preferred way if there's a chance your `.ui` file contains a menubar and menubar items.

```
menubar = self.menuBar()
```

Also, you can't add `QMenuBars` to layouts - [from the docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qmenubar.html):

> There is no need to lay out a menu bar. It automatically sets its own geometry to the top of the parent widget and changes it appropriately whenever the parent is resized.

Comment: Also, it looks like you're not actually calling `initUI` in your example.  It should be `initUI()`